# Fresh Installs of RVM and Ruby 2.1.1 - dyld library/pathing error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, dyld

I have been trying to install RVM and Ruby 2.1.1 onto my new Mac (OS 10.9.2), and everything seems to be going well until I try to install any version of Ruby.

My input

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.1
```

So far so good...

```
ruby-2.1.1 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.1.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.1.1 - #configure
ruby-2.1.1 - #download
ruby-2.1.1 - #validate archive
ruby-2.1.1 - #extract
ruby-2.1.1 - #validate binary
ruby-2.1.1 - #setup
ruby-2.1.1 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-2.1.1 - #downloading rubygems-2.2.2
ruby-2.1.1 - #extracting rubygems-2.2.2....
ruby-2.1.1 - #removing old rubygems.........
```

But then...

```
ruby-2.1.1 - #installing rubygems-2.2.2.
Error running 'env GEM_HOME= GEM_PATH= /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -d /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/setup.rb --verbose',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/log/1395654507_ruby-2.1.1/rubygems.install.log
[2014-03-24 02:48:47] /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
current path: /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/bin
command(7): env GEM_HOME= GEM_PATH= /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -d /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/setup.rb --verbose
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/versions/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
/Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 411: 14265 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$ruby_path" -rrbconfig -e '\
    File.open("'"$config_path"'","w") { |file|
      RbConfig::CONFIG.sort.each{|key,value|
        file.write("#{key.gsub(/\.|-/,"_")}=\"#{value.gsub("$","\\$")}\"\n")
      }
    }
  ' > /dev/null 2>&1
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/versions/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
Empty path passed to certificates update, functions stack: requirements_osx_update_openssl_cert_run rvm_requiremnts_fail_or_run_action __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby_except_jruby external_import_setup external_import main
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-2.1.1 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/dylanoshea/.rvm/tmp/5021*
```

I have repeatedly tried deleting, imploding, removing and un/reinstalling all of my RVM components and Ruby versions, but it doesn't make a difference -- I still get this error. Curiously, the broken path refers to an "mpapis" who is one of the developers of RVM.

`dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/`**mpapis**`/.sm/pkg/versions/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`

Any help?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It looks it's a temporary bug: https://twitter.com/mpapis/status/447926386314186752.
The `disable-binary` option worked for me:

```
rvm reinstall 2.1.1 --disable-binary
```

**EDIT - better solution**

I see that some people still have this problem. Today much better solution is to update RVM like this:

```
rvm get stable
```

The problem was caused by RVM - it had some paths hard-coded into ruby binary versions. But this issue was already fixed and currently there's no need in compiling ruby locally. All you need is to get most recent RVM version.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick. I was worried that only the error message was hard-coded with a bad path and that it was still a fundamental problem on my end!

Comment: I'm a javascript guy and this rvm business can be a pain. Thanks for making this not painful.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem for me as well. One question though, will the `--disable-binary` flag have any adverse side effects? What exactly does this flag do?

Comment: @Leif, it means that rvm will download source code and compile it on your computer. Without this flag rvm downloads already compiled binary distribution.

Comment: I had the same issue with rvm and ruby 2.1.3. --disable-binary cured that as well

Comment: They just released 2.1.4 yesterday.  I had the same problem and using --disable-binary fixed the problem.

Comment: The problem is in RVM, not in Ruby. So updating RVM should work for all rubies. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

as per https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2732 :

rvm reinstall 2.1.1 --disable-binary

should allow you to install it.

also setting your "rvm use" to the most recent version of ruby on your "rvm list" also helped me.

and the issue is now closed on github, so in a couple of days (question : does anyone know the usual turn around for rvm patches?) the fix should be up on the rvm.io site and running "rvm get stable" will update your intallation with the patch