# RVM Installation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

my RVM gets installed eventually, but the log shows up 2 errors:

```
Error running 'env GEM_HOME= GEM_PATH= /Users/syc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -d       /Users/syc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/setup.rb',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/syc/.rvm/log/1395676829_ruby-2.1.1/rubygems.install.log
```

and

```
Empty path passed to certificates update, functions stack: requirements_osx_update_openssl_cert_run rvm_requiremnts_fail_or_run_action __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby_except_jruby external_import_setup external_import main
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-2.1.1 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
```

May I kindly find out what has gone wrong? I've searched the net thoroughly and could not find the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It appears that an RVM developer included a path to his personal machine on a binary build by mistake. You can get around this issue for now by running `rvm install 2.1.1 --disable-binary` as described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607525/1172675).