# Error when installing Ruby 2.1.3 with RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.1.3 with RVM.  I have the latest version of XCode installed and I have a clean install of rvm.

I'm basically doing

```
rvm autolibs brew
rvm install ruby-2.1.3
```

Everything looks to be working ok, but then I get this error:

**Empty path passed to certificates update, functions stack: requirements_osx_update_openssl_cert_run rvm_requiremnts_fail_or_run_action __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby_except_jruby external_import_setup external_import main**

The only references I can get to this is an issue with Ruby 2.1.1 when a developer checked in a hardcoded path, but I can't see how this is related.

Here is the full trace I'm getting:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.3.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.1.3 - #configure
ruby-2.1.3 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 6864k  100 6864k    0     0  1143k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 1412k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.1.3 - #validate archive
ruby-2.1.3 - #extract
ruby-2.1.3 - #validate binary
ruby-2.1.3 - #setup
ruby-2.1.3 - #gemset created /Users/jaco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
ruby-2.1.3 - #importing gemset /Users/jaco/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems......................................................................
ruby-2.1.3 - #generating global wrappers..............
ruby-2.1.3 - #gemset created /Users/jaco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
ruby-2.1.3 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/jaco/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.1.3 - #generating default wrappers..............
/Users/jaco/.rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 480:  2804 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$ruby_path" -rrbconfig -e '\
    File.open("'"$config_path"'","w") { |file|
      RbConfig::CONFIG.sort.each{|key,value|
        file.write("#{key.gsub(/\.|-/,"_")}=\"#{value.gsub("$","\\$")}\"\n")
      }
    }
  ' > /dev/null 2>&1
Empty path passed to certificates update, functions stack: requirements_osx_update_openssl_cert_run rvm_requiremnts_fail_or_run_action __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby_except_jruby external_import_setup external_import main
```

Comment: I found a thread mentioning just `Trace/BPT trap: 5`, which appears to be caused either by a stale terminal session or some strange character unintentionally added to `/etc/paths.d`.  Does the output of `echo $PATH` look normal? See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113379/how-to-debug-trace-bpt-trap-5

Comment: Did you update rvm?  If so, there should have been a message to run `$ rvm requirements`.  Recently, I had some problems installing ruby 2.1 after upgrading rvm on OSX 10.6.8.  The command `$ rvm requirements` did something with openssl, which screwed up some of my rubies and gemsets, and I had to do re-install rubies 2.0 + like this:  `$ rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.2 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/opt/openssl`  You could try installing with that same flag.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same problem

`rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary`

worked for me
(based on [Fresh Installs of RVM and Ruby 2.1.1 - dyld library/pathing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605921/fresh-installs-of-rvm-and-ruby-2-1-1-dyld-library-pathing-error)).

Comment: Thanks, I'm still rather mystified as to why this is the case.  I think I might not have started out with `rvm autolibs brew` which is now screwing with me

Comment: Just a minor notice: `rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.3 --disable-binary` you need to put a `ruby-` before its version number. Otherwise didn't work.

Comment: When I do that it consumes cpu and never finishes

Comment: FWIW, it works as-is for me on `rvm 1.25.33 (stable)`

Comment: Same problem, same solution for rvm 1.26.0 and Ruby 2.1.4 on Mavericks.

Comment: I had a similar problem with 2.1.4, `rvm reinstall 2.1.4 --disable-binary` worked for me. thanks to @csage for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick fix:**

```
brew install gpg
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
rvm get stable
```

**Longer description:**

From the output of 'rvm get stable'

```
Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of 
signatures when GPG software found.

Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading 
the signatures).
```

Adn then during installation of ruby-2.1.4 I got:

```
GPG signature verification failed for '$HOME/.rvm/archives/rvm-installer' - 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer.asc'!
try downloading the signatures:

gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3

or if it fails:

command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -

the key can be compared with:

https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

Using that output, I came up with the quick fix listed above. This means that you can still use binary rubies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
And finally I found this solution:

To solve the issue I just had to execute two commands as following:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
```

After that, I ran this command:

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary
```

And it works, it was installed successfully for me.

[Install Ruby 2.1.3 on Mac OS X - Mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/820364/ruby-installation-issues-with-rvm)

Hope it could be useful for you!