# rvm install 2.1.4 <--- fails on Mac OS X mavricks

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Trying to install ruby 2.1.4 using latest rvm on Mac OS X Mavericks...

rvm fails to install ruby 2.1.4

Cryptic error message about empty default gemset ??

Tried installing twice.

I was able to install ruby 2.1.3 few days ago, and all was okay

Help appreciated

```
helabed@hani-elabeds-MacBook-Pro:~/rails-proj $ rvm info

ruby-2.1.3@rspec-2:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin hani-elabeds-MacBook-Pro.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.9/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "21 minutes 6 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/helabed/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.3p242"
    date:         "2014-09-19"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin14.0"
    patchlevel:   "2014-09-19 revision 47630"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rspec-2"
    ruby:         "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rspec-2/bin:/Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/Users/helabed/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/helabed/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/helabed/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/helabed/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rspec-2"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rspec-2:/Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/helabed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "rspec-2"


helabed@hani-elabeds-MacBook-Pro:~/rails-proj $ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.7.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.3.0)
helabed@hani-elabeds-MacBook-Pro:~/rails-proj $ rvm reinstall 2.1.4
ruby-2.1.4 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.1.4..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.4.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.1.4 - #configure
ruby-2.1.4 - #download
ruby-2.1.4 - #validate archive
ruby-2.1.4 - #extract
ruby-2.1.4 - #validate binary
ruby-2.1.4 - #setup
ruby-2.1.4 - #gemset created /Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global
ruby-2.1.4 - #importing gemset /Users/helabed/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems........................................................................
ruby-2.1.4 - #generating global wrappers..............
ruby-2.1.4 - #gemset created /Users/helabed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4
ruby-2.1.4 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/helabed/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.1.4 - #generating default wrappers..............
/Users/helabed/.rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 490: 17899 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$ruby_path" -rrbconfig -e '\
    File.open("'"$config_path"'","w") { |file|
      RbConfig::CONFIG.sort.each{|key,value|
        file.write("#{key.gsub(/\.|-/,"_")}=\"#{value.gsub("$","\\$")}\"\n")
      }
    }
  ' > /dev/null 2>&1
Empty path passed to certificates update, functions stack: requirements_osx_update_openssl_cert_run rvm_requiremnts_fail_or_run_action __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby __rvm_osx_ssl_certs_ensure_for_ruby_except_jruby external_import_setup external_import main
Making gemset ruby-2.1.4 pristine................................................................
Making gemset ruby-2.1.4@global pristine.................................................................
helabed@hani-elabeds-MacBook-Pro:~/rails-proj $
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. A good solution can be found [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148600/error-when-installing-ruby-2-1-3-with-rvm).

Comment: @csage thank you, all working now...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with 2.1.4,

```
rvm reinstall 2.1.4 --disable-binary
```

worked for me. thanks to @csage for the pointer.

similar issue here

[Error when installing Ruby 2.1.3 with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148600/error-when-installing-ruby-2-1-3-with-rvm)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues where 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 hang on the compilation step.

This solved my issue:

`rvm install 2.1.4 -- --with-setjmp-type=setjmp`

[original source of fix](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3050#issuecomment-56666232)